# POST formular is submiting wrong values of a hidden input

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, post

I have the problem, that my POST formular in `html5` submit a wrong value of a hidden input. But, more information´s might would be helpful.

```js
function changeActivity () {
    if(document.getElementById('input.edit.user.activity').value=="0"){
        document.getElementById('input.edit.user.activityButon').className="btn-block btn-lg btn-danger";
        document.getElementById('input.edit.user.activityButon').innerHTML="Mark user as inactive";
        document.getElementById('input.edit.user.activity').value="1";
    }else{
        document.getElementById('input.edit.user.activityButon').className="btn-block btn-lg btn-success btn-block";
        document.getElementById('input.edit.user.activityButon').innerHTML="Mark user as active";
        document.getElementById('input.edit.user.activity').value="0";
    }
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="user_activity" id="input.edit.user.activity" value="1">
    <button class="btn-block btn-lg btn-danger btn-block" type="button" onclick="changeActivity()" id="input.edit.user.activityButon" style="border-style: none">Mark user as inactive</button>
    <button class="btn-block btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit" style="border-style: none;margin-bottom: 0.3%;">Update user</button>
</form>
```

So, when i submit in PHP the `$_POST['user_activity']` always 0 (String)`.

Edit: i don´t know what it was, but now it works!

Comment: Works fine in my side..

Comment: yes working fine you can check input.edit.user.activity in function with  console.log(document.getElementById('input.edit.user.activity').value);

Comment: you can post form another page because when you submit page it's reload page and input value set 0 again.

Comment: @Cripi - How you are sending form data to the the server side. By using any AJAX call or default POST method of HTML Form.

Answer (score 0):

works fine. But if you are using some old browser means it may not work. It is not a good practise to use dot(.) in id. since (.) is usually used with class in css and JavaScript. It will works anyway but it is not a good practise. So if you are using old browser, change the dot(.) from id in input element as well as the JavaScript function